# Express.js Route orgainisation

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, code-organization

When I set-up some Routes i normaly do it like this:

```
app.get('/x', function(req, res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/.../index.html'));});
```

The Problem with this is if you have JS or CSS in the Route Folders you cant host them.

So often I just added

```
app.get('/public/.../js/index.js', function(req, res) {res.sendFile (__dirname + '/public/.../js/index.js');});
app.get('/public/.../css/style.css', function(req, res) {res.sendFile (__dirname + '/public/.../css/style.css');});
```

just below the Route to make the JS and CSS accessible.

I already host library with express static

```
app.use('/lib', express.static('lib'));
```

But that is not Possible for JS and CSS in the Route folders (/public/.../js)

> - Is There a better Way to organize my files that are in the route folders ?

Comment: You should be able to access ur JS folder within that /lib folder ..i usually put all client (scripts, styles, images) into one folder in your case lib ..and u can host it with express.static

Comment: If you put all static files in one or more directories by themselves, then you can easily make routes to them all with `express.static()` statements.  And, then adjust the paths in your HTML files that point to those static resources to line up with the routes you created.

Comment: I thought about this bevor but decided not to do it because then you would have everything in 10 Folders and then I would have the same Problem it would not be that organised but this time not in the code, But in the File system. But I can't find another solution so this is my only option. Lets see if someone comes up with a solution .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  Why do you want CSS and (clientside) JS files in your routes folder?  That seems to be a poor organizational choice as the premise of your question.

Comment: Yeah you understood it perfectly. I started this project im still working on when i had 0 knowledge of node. The thing is at Beginning i thought this was even better organised than haveing an extra folder because if i wanted to work on a certain page i would have everything in one folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use virtual path, keeping your current directory structure, adding following route you can refer all your static files with /static prefix from under ./public subdirectory:

```
app.use('/static', express.static('public'))
```

E.g. you would be able to refer http://your_server/static/public/.../js/index.js. *Please be aware, that in such case all files under /public might be accessed via /static prefix, so you should not have server code or server configs there.*

Ideally for clarity you should host and refer all your static files from one root folder with type subfolders (e.g. /static/js, /static/css):

```
app.use('/static', express.static('static'))
```